# MySQL Exact phrase match

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm using python and the mysqldb module to search a database for a user input.
I have tested the python and established a connection to the server and database. It's the SQL code giving me trouble.
My SQl is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM panda WHERE MATCH(Question) AGAINST('"{0}"')
```

I'm using python so the {0} is the user input. that bit works. For some reason it won't match the exact phrase to whats in the column on the database. For example, if the user inputs 'See you' the database matches it as 'I want to see you' not just 'See you'. Is there any way to get the specific phrase? I have tried using boolean mode and regex but they don't work.

edit: Thank you all. All of your methods worked, it just turned out I hadn't formatted the SQL correctly. sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Could you make the question a little clearer? What is the phrase in your column you want to search? Do you want it to match when the user types the exact phrase?

Comment: Currently the phrase is 'See you' and yes, exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [MATCH ... AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match). What you want is a simple comparison, try something like this:

SELECT * FROM panda WHERE Question = {0};

Comment: All I'm getting when i try and try it that way are NoneType errors because the module hasn't found the value in the database.

Comment: Did you make sure the value is in the database? Check with `SELECT * FROM panda` or `SELECT Question, Question = {0} FROM panda`.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely in the database.

Comment: What's the columns type (`VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, `TEXT`, ...)?

Comment: LONGTEXT. Should it be something else?

Comment: Well I doubt you want to insert strings with more than 16 million characters so that you chose a column type that can take billions of characters each (`VARCHAR` sounds more appropriate for a column named "Question"). What's the output of `SELECT * FROM panda` and `SELECT * FROM panda WHERE Question = 'See you'`?

Comment: The output is a NoneType

Comment: Just tested again, turns out when i was using your most recent code in the comments i forgot to change 'See you' to '{0}'. It now works perfectly. thank you very much. I'm pretty confident on my SQL skills now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Then why don't use just use WHERE Question = '"{0}"'

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use python and sql together to search for a certain column 'Question' with a value equal to inputVar and get the entire entry in row.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "password", "MY_DATABASE")
cursor=db.cursor()

sql="SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Question = '%s';" %inputVar; 
    try:      
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        print row[0] #assuming 1st column is 'Question' column.
        db.commit()
    except:
        print ("ROLLBACK!!!")
        db.rollback()
```

Comment: Is MY_DB the table name or database name?

Comment: Table name. I've edited it. Also added initialization.

Comment: I have everything there correct. When I run it i get an error:

Comment: inputVar must be a string. How is the user inputting the character? It seems like it's a tuple instead of a string in your case. Use input command `inputVar = raw_input("Enter phrase")`?

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH ... AGAINST`, also known as FULLTEXT search, is performing as designed for you. Its purpose is to dig into quantities of text and find rows that contain matching text to your query.

Notice that a FULLTEXT index only sees the first 750 or so characters of the text in the column.

It's useful functionality, because it works even if random punctuation or other words show up in the text. `WHERE column = 'value'` demands exact matches.

You might try this query: It will present the results roughly in increasing length order. This will push "See you" ahead of "I want to see you" in the order of results.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM panda
 WHERE MATCH(Question) AGAINST('"{0}"')
 ORDER BY CEIL(LOG2(LENGTH(Question))) ASC,
       MATCH(Question) AGAINST('"{0}"')
```

Notice that the expression `MATCH(Question) AGAINST('"{0}"')` produces a number specifying the closeness of the match when you use it in a `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clause.

Notice also that the expression `CEIL(LOG2(LENGTH(Question)))` in your `ORDER BY` clause groups your results by chunks based on length.  It groups lengths of 3-4 together, then lengths 5-8, 9-16, and so forth.